# MVC 4 and Knockout

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, knockout.js

I am working on a relatively simple web application, and my supervisor recommended that I use a combination of Knockout, MVC, and Bootstrap to accomplish my task. Unfortunately, I got stuck on what is probably a trivial part of the project.

I have seen a lot of Knockout tutorials out there, and have been trying to mimic their simplest one, found here:
http://learn.knockoutjs.com/#/?tutorial=intro

Unfortunately, none of my data-binding appears to work. The observables never retain their assigned value.

I also ran across [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055336/how-to-use-knockout-js-with-asp-net-mvc-viewmodels?rq=1) thread while searching, and tried to mimic it, to no avail. Basically, I would just like to know how to properly implement Knockout data binding in Visual Studio MVC4. Here is my HTML code, a lot of which I ripped off from the thread mentioned above.

```
@model FluidBedSimulation.Models.BedState
@using Newtonsoft.Json

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>Index</h2>

@if (false)
{
    <script src="../../Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

}
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/knockout-2.2.0.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>



<script type="text/javascript">

    this.BedMass = ko.observable(1);
    this.BedWaterMass = ko.observable(1);
    this.binderFraction = ko.observable(1);

    (function () {
        var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
           var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
           ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

       });

</script>




@*grab values from the view model directly*@

<p>Bed Weight: <strong data-bind="text: BedMass" id="BedMass"></strong></p>
<p>H2O Bed Weight: <strong data-bind="text: BedWaterMass" id="BedWaterMass"></strong></p>
<p>Fraction of Binder in Spray Solution: <strong data-bind="text: binderFraction" id="binderFraction"></strong></p>

<p>
    Enter the Bed Mass: 
            <input data-bind="value: BedMass" />

            @*Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BedMass, new { data_bind = "value: BedMass" })*@
</p>
<p>
    Enter the H2O Mass in the Bed: 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.BedWaterMass, new { data_bind = "value: BedWaterMass" })
</p>
<p>
    Enter the Fraction of Binder in the Spray Solution: 
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.binderFraction, new { data_bind = "value: binderFraction" })
</p>

<button data-bind="click: Simulate">Simulate</button>
```

Here is the simple model I have...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace FluidBedSimulation.Models
{
    public class BedState
    {
        public double BedMass { get; set; }
        public double BedWaterMass { get; set; }
        public int binderFraction { get; set; }
        public double EvapRate { get; set; }
        public double SprayRate { get; set; }
        public double AirTemp { get; set; }
        public double AirFlow { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the simple controller. Nothing fancy.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using FluidBedSimulation.Models;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


namespace FluidBedSimulation.Controllers
{
    public class SimulationController : Controller
    {
        //
        // GET: /Simulation/

        public ActionResult Index()
        {


            BedState state = new BedState
            {
                BedMass = 0,
                BedWaterMass = 0,
                binderFraction = 0,
                AirFlow = 0,
                AirTemp = 0,
                EvapRate = 0,
                SprayRate = 0
            };

            FluidBed bed = new FluidBed
            {
                FluidBedStates = new List<BedState> { state }
            };


            return View(state);
        }

    }
}
```

If you guys could get me started on this thing I would really appreciate it. Otherwise I might just have to stick to good ol' JQuery and html. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You shouldn't have quotes around `@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))`. The `JSON.Encode` should wrap it already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your using the knockout.mapping plugin but I don't see you including the mapping plugin js file. You need to include it after the knockout lib file: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout.mapping/tree/master/build/output.

Also, your anonymous function is never run. To make it immediately invoked you need to end it with parentheses like this:

```
(function () {
    var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
       var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(model);
       ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for the help lagerone, I uploaded and included the mapping file, and corrected the JS function, but I am still not getting anything from the bindings. 

When I enter values in my text boxes, tags like these
`<strong data-bind="text: BedMass" id="BedMass"></strong></p>`
do not update... do you know why that might be?

Comment: Well, you have created and bound your viewModel before the DOM is rendered. That could be the issue. Either wrap your viewModel creation in a $(function(){}) (since your using jQuery) or move it to the bottom of the page, right before your closing body tag.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend checking out a open source project i have put together called [**Shoelace**](https://github.com/hylander0/Shoelace)

Much like **@lagerone** described in his post with mapping the **MVC model** to a **Knockout** model (so you don't have to maintain two model definitions), i have done was well with a different pattern.

[**UserList.chtml**](https://github.com/hylander0/Shoelace/blob/master/Shoelace/Views/Account/UserList.cshtml#L110) (MVC view)

```
@Html.PartialResource(@<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/app/Views/Account/userlist.viewmodel.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>, "js")
@Html.PartialResource(
@<script type="text/javascript">
     $(function () {
         var viewModelObj = APP.userListViewModel(ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(Model.ToJson())));
            ko.applyBindings(viewModelObj, document.getElementById("cntnrUserList"));
        });

    </script>, "js")
```

However, My pattern passes the model into a ViewModel object to extend if for validation, complex observables, event function definitions, etc.

[**userListViewModel**](https://github.com/hylander0/Shoelace/blob/master/Shoelace/Scripts/app/Views/Account/userlist.viewmodel.js) (javascript class)

```
APP.userListViewModel = function (model) {
    var self = model;
    $.extend(APP.manageProfileViewModel, model);
    self.selectedUser = ko.observable({});
    self.confirmDelete = function () {
        $("#hdDeleteUserId").val(this.userId());
    };
    self.performDelete = function () {
        //alert("performDelete called for UserId: " + $("#hdDeleteUserId").val());
        var url = APP.helpers.prepareRelativeUrl("Account/DeleteUser");
        APP.helpers.performAjaxPost(url,
                JSON.stringify({ UserId: $("#hdDeleteUserId").val() }),
                function (result) {
                    if (result != null && result.success == true) {
                        alert('Your profile has been update.');
                        location.reload();
                    }
                },
                function () {
                    alert('An error has occured. Please try again.');
                });
    };
    self.cancel = function () {
        //alert("cancelDelete called");
    };
    self.showUserPermissions = function () {
        self.selectedUser(this);
        //$("#hdPermissionsUserId").val(this.userId());
    };
    self.saveUserPermissions = function () {
        var url = APP.helpers.prepareRelativeUrl("Account/SaveUserRoles");
        APP.helpers.performAjaxPost(url,
                ko.toJSON(self.selectedUser),
                function (result) {
                    //Do nothing.
                },
                function () {
                    alert('An error has occured. Please try again.');
                });
    };
    return ko.validatedObservable(self);
};
```

[**Shoelace**](https://github.com/hylander0/Shoelace) employs the following bits:

- **ASP.NET MVC 4 using Razor (CSHTML)**
- **jQuery**
- **Knockout.js** *(using client bindings/templates instead of Razor bindings)*
- **Knockout.Validation.js**
- **Knockout.mapping.js**
- **[Twitter Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) Responsive Design**
- **[Bootstrap-Admin-Theme by Vincent Gabriel](https://github.com/VinceG/Bootstrap-Admin-Theme)**
- **The WebMatrix SimpleMembership Implementation**
- **Entity Framework 5 with Code First Data Modeling**