# Creating a KnockoutJS Model From an ASP.NET MVC complex model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, asp.net-mvc-5, knockout-mapping-plugin

I would like to create knockout viewModel from asp.net MVC model using ko.mapping.fromJS() method but my form didn't populating values.

In view I created script looks like that:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            var tmp = @Html.Raw(Model.ToJson());
            var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(tmp);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    </script>
```

*@Html.Raw(Model.ToJson()* returns value

```
 {"id":1,
"surveyCode":null,
"title":"Życie",
"description":"Ankieta, w której zadawane będą pytania na temat codziennego życia ",
"dateStart":"2013-12-12T00:00:00",
"dateEnd":"2014-12-30T00:00:00",
"createDate":"2014-01-07T03:23:16.053",
"lastModification":"2014-01-07T03:23:16.053",
"isActive":false,
"questions":[{"id":1,
            "surveyID":1,
            "content":"Co jesz na śniadanie?",
            "tips":"wybierz jedną odpowiedź",
            "questionType":1,
            "isRequired":true,
            "answers":  [{"id":1,
                                "questionID":1,
                                "answerContent":"Jajecznicę",
                                "isOpenAnswer":false},
                         {"id":2,
                                "questionID":1,
                                "answerContent":"Kiełbaski",
                                "isOpenAnswer":false},
                         {"id":3,
                                "questionID":1,
                                "answerContent":"Płatki na mleku",
                                "isOpenAnswer":false},
                         {"id":4,
                                "questionID":1,
                                "answerContent":"Inne",
                                "isOpenAnswer":true}]},
             {"id":2,
             "surveyID":1,
             "content":"Czym się zajmujesz w życiu?",
             "tips":"napisz krótką historię",
             "questionType":3,
             "isRequired":true,
             "answers":[]}]}
```

but when I want to bind 'title' property to `<span>` `<span data-bind="text:title"></span>`  it is not working. When I run my app in firefox and turn on firebug script console and set breakpiont to line `var tmp = @Html.Raw(Model.ToJson());` returns correct value, press F10 going to next line `var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(tmp);` and finally press F10 and nothing happen, script not execute next line `ko.applyBindings(viewModel);`.

And it is my question. Is it possible to mapp my mvc model using knockout mapping plugin automacly? or maybe should I do some manualy staf to map mvc model to knockout viewModel.

I'm looking for answers on this sites:
[link1](http://jason-mitchell.com/web-development/creating-a-knockoutjs-model-from-an-asp-net-mvc-model/)
and
[stackowerflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055336/how-to-use-knockout-js-with-asp-net-mvc-viewmodels)
but maybe I didn't understand this posts.

**Edit**

my view looks like this:

```
@using Inżynierka.Extensions
@model Inżynierka.Models.Survey

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SurveyAnswer</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        Title: <span data-bind="text:title"></span>


    </div>
}


@section Scripts {
        <script src="../../Scripts/jQuery.tmpl.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/knockout.validation.js"></script>
        <script src="../../Scripts/knockout.knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var tmp = @Html.Raw(Model.ToJson());
            var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(tmp);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        </script>
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

**Edit 2**

It is html sourse of my page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.0.0.js'></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Create</title>
    <link href="/Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="/Content/site.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Ankietyy</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="/Surveys">Moje Ankiety</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/">Strona Gł&#243;wna</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/About">O Projekcie</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/Home/Contact">Kontakt</a></li>
                </ul>
                <form action="/Account/LogOff" class="navbar-right" id="logoutForm" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="fWDZFmyGqJyU3ATUf2IbHDdkbo22bzObUMwUfxfqwXIiqGvRYzMhApWS3I5GkkHnZD7ieDxLfh84s2-prLDtSGeE6_D7p7cT-fmQBszeM06p-fZ7RzhOPn0P8EDftLRwT8YQA8t2U56dlLX_lx3G4Q2" />    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
            <a href="/Account/Manage" title="Manage">Witaj Bartek!</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:document.getElementById('logoutForm').submit()">Wyloguj się</a></li>
    </ul>
</form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container body-content">




<form action="/SurveyAnswer/CompleteSurvey/1" method="post"><input name="__RequestVerificationToken" type="hidden" value="KOALGZbw0WhFlBV4LHx530Oen59aBWF62b6s58GIUikx3A62uhcAi3-74auJpLtI4fYj9kmcPjlgNu1TeuNrYukpFlll1cGCOIcjjewtFou4M9C3_bHDFk7UoZk_tKpw7SxcXa3UbgwIj4ZhCRM6_g2" />    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SurveyAnswer</h4>
        <hr />


        Title: <span data-bind="text:title"></span>


    </div>
</form><script type="text/javascript">
            var tmp = {"id":1,"surveyCode":null,"title":"Życie","description":"Ankieta, w której zadawane będą pytania na temat codziennego życia ","dateStart":"2013-12-12T00:00:00","dateEnd":"2014-12-30T00:00:00","createDate":"2014-01-07T03:23:16.053","lastModification":"2014-01-07T03:23:16.053","isActive":false,"questions":[{"id":1,"surveyID":1,"content":"Co jesz na śniadanie?","tips":"wybierz jedną odpowiedź","questionType":1,"isRequired":true,"answers":[{"id":1,"questionID":1,"answerContent":"Jajecznicę","isOpenAnswer":false},{"id":2,"questionID":1,"answerContent":"Kiełbaski","isOpenAnswer":false},{"id":3,"questionID":1,"answerContent":"Płatki na mleku","isOpenAnswer":false},{"id":4,"questionID":1,"answerContent":"Inne","isOpenAnswer":true}]},{"id":2,"surveyID":1,"content":"Czym się zajmujesz w życiu?","tips":"napisz krótką historię","questionType":3,"isRequired":true,"answers":[]},{"id":14,"surveyID":1,"content":"Pytanie końcowe","tips":"napisz","questionType":1,"isRequired":true,"answers":[{"id":9,"questionID":14,"answerContent":"test","isOpenAnswer":false},{"id":10,"questionID":14,"answerContent":"test2","isOpenAnswer":false},{"id":11,"questionID":14,"answerContent":"test3","isOpenAnswer":false}]}],"surveyAnswers":[],"codeForUsers":[]};
            var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(tmp);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
</script>



        <hr />
        <footer>
            <p>&copy; 2014 - My ASP.NET Application</p>
        </footer>
    </div>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/respond.js"></script>


    <script src="../../Scripts/jQuery.tmpl.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/knockout.validation.js"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>

    <script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>



<!-- Visual Studio Browser Link -->
<script type="application/json" id="__browserLink_initializationData">
    {"appName":"Firefox","requestId":"9f8e517696004299808eb3caccb0e136"}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:11897/dc47e85290da49019e6425ddd16f962a/browserLink" async="async"></script>
<!-- End Browser Link -->

</body>
</html>
```

**Answer for my issue**

View should looks like that:

```
@using Inżynierka.Extensions
@model Inżynierka.Models.Survey

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SurveyAnswer</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        Title: <span data-bind="text:title"></span>


    </div>
}



@section Scripts {
    <script src="../../Scripts/knockout-3.0.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="../../Scripts/knockout.mapping-latest.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            var tmp = @Html.Raw(Model.ToJson());
            var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(tmp);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    </script>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Thanks everyone for replies, specially for @VolodymyrBilyachat whose advices were most relevant.

Comment: Can you share your view?

Comment: @Volodymyr Bilyachat I added my View to post

Comment: Move the template script below your knockout script and then wrap your view model in a document.ready function

Comment: I have fixed you view try it now

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat html source code attached

Comment: @BartłomiejZalewski I see and its strange since all was right, because as you see your scripts are on bottom. So yu have this issues in FF right?

Comment: Move scripts again how they was and you know what try to remove other scripts left only knockout and knockout mapper, since its getting strange....

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat could you explain me what means 'FF'?

Comment: FireFox :) but it works in FF so could be issue with other scripts. Try to remove all only knockout should be there...

Comment: @VolodymyrBilyachat your last comment is the answer!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! :) I don't know why but now it is working :) Than you very much dude :) You don't let me give it up, cheers!

Comment: I will update my answer :) and you can mark it as answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after you post source, then other idea what it could is that some scripts are conflicting, try to remove scripts and left only knockout ones

Comment: ehhh... I'm sure you kave right but it still not showing my 'title'. Mayby i should give up for a moment with knockout mapping :P. Thank you vary much for your replies.

Comment: @user3187246 no never give up lets fix it, can you please render page and send me html (view source)

Comment: I observe that when I want to debug it in firebug script console <code>var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(tmp);</code> this make that firefox stop working and didn't answer.

Comment: thats why please attach html source of you page.

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your knockout view model in a document.ready function

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $document.ready(function() {
            var tmp = @Html.Raw(Model.ToJson());
            var viewModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(tmp);
            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);});
    </script>
```

Also note that your viewModel isn't a true view model at that point so consider using a view model that contains the ko.observable property 'myData' or something to hold your data and then applying bindings

Answer (score -1):

For **complex** models I don't believe mappings and simply, I'm parsing json on my own and populate model via loops, ifs and so on. I think, this isn't the worst solution, because debugging and fixing data becomes simplier.