# How to apply dynamically background color to any DOM in the View from Knockout.js Viewmodel property?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

I want to apply backcolor from dynamically using knockout.js Viewmodel.

**Like In HTML**

```
<table border="1"  > // I need back color over here
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
…………
```

**My ViewModel**

```
function SelfEmpPerformance() {
    var that = this;
    that.departcompetencebackcolor = ko.observable('');
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        cache: false,
        url: baseUrl() + "/EmpSelfReview/GetSelfReviewData",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            if (data.Success == 1) {
                 that.departcompetencebackcolor(data.SelfEmpPerformance.
                                  departcompetencebackcolor);
                                   }
                                 }
            });
   }
```

I need to set color code on table which is in the departcompetencebackcolor property .

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use knockout.js with ASP.NET MVC ViewModels?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11055336/how-to-use-knockout-js-with-asp-net-mvc-viewmodels)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using style binding. You can check how to use it here http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/style-binding.html

In your case the table definition should look like this:

```
<table border="1" data-bind="style: { backgroundColor : departcompetencebackcolor() }">
```